# parse decimale toFixed(2) on decimals which are not 0

Tags: javascript

**The aim is to have 2 decimals without counting 0**

1.2234 => 1.22

0.2345 => 0.23

0.02345 => 0.023 (instead of 0.02)

0.0000002345 => 0.00000023 (instead of 0)

0.0000002346545645645646465465 => 0.00000023 (instead of 0)

0.002035 => 0.002 instead of 0)

I want to parse toFixed(2) but on the decimals which are not 0. How to do this properly ?

Comment: so, 0.003040 what would the result?

Comment: 0.003 The aim is to have 2 decimals without counting 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think from example what you meant remove last 2 digits instead of making it fixed into 2 decimals.

To do so, heres my approach.

```js
 function removeLastDigit(number, amount = 2)
{
  const numberString = number.toString();
  if(numberString.indexOf('.') === -1) return number;
  let numberLength = numberString.length;
  for(; numberLength >= 0 && amount; numberLength--){
    if (numberString[numberLength] !== '0') amount--;
  }
  return +numberString.slice(0, numberLength);
}
let num = 0.003040;
console.log(removeLastDigit(num)) //0.03
```

Comment: no that's not my question, I have updated for more clarity

Comment: then easily modify the logic, ill update

Comment: You can try the solution